# Собрал программу CMake на Debian 12.2. Не могу запустить ее на Red Hat 4.8.5

Tags: c++, linux, c, cmake

Нет опыта в разработке на С++ под Linux. (пишу на C#)
Возникла потребность написать парсер который работает с Tcp сокетом Linux.
Написал программу с помощью Ide JetBrains Clion, сборщик Cmake.
Программу сбилдил и успешно запустил через терминал на той же машине на которой разрабатывал.
./myProgram

Версия компилятора на машине разработки
g++ --version
g++ (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0

Нужно перенести программу на сервер - он работает под Red Hat 4.8.5
Версия компилятора на сервере
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5  (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

При попытке запуска на сервере не понимает команду запуска
./myProgram

пишет что не является Bash командой.

Подскажите в чем дело? нужно настроить CMake как то специфически или я не правильно запускаю?

Comment: Вам необходимо собрать второй бинарь под Red Hat.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста где про это почитать? я так понял это вторая конфигурация CMake?

Comment: Выполняйте сборку на машине  Red Hat. Вероятно при портировании на эту платформу понадобятся еще дополнительные модификации в коде.

Comment: Уже почитал по Cmake.  Сначала сгенерирую Build через Ninja потом соберу этот Build на целевой машине. Спасибо за участие.

Comment: Я имел в виду перенести только CMakeLists и src. Потом сгенерировать паку Build на целевой машине, потом выполнить сам build.